# Bind <select> with ng-options and ng-model where model has composite key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular service that returns a list of objects that have a "composite" key made up of two parts. I don't see how I can write the bindings so that they properly re-bind existing data. Here's my current attempt:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("fooCtrl", function() {
    // This comes from an Angular service / back-end:
    this.options = [
      { part1: 3, part2: 101, displayName: "Option 3-101" },
      { part1: 4, part2: 651, displayName: "Option 4-651" },
      { part1: 4, part2: 999, displayName: "Option 4-999" }
    ];

    this.item = { selectedOption: { part1: 4, part2: 651 } };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="fooCtrl as vm">
  <select ng-options="option.displayName for option in vm.options track by part1 + '-' + part2"
          ng-model="vm.item.selectedOption"></select>
  <hr>
  Debug info:
  <pre>{{vm.item | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

However, the above does not work: it should be selecting `"Option 4-651"` on loading, but doesn't do this.

Note that the `displayName` is added client side to the options, but it is *not* in the `selectedOption` when it is loaded. I don't mind if the `selectedOption` becomes an object that *does* have the `displayName` property, the back-end will just ignore it anyways because there is no equivalent backing property for it (I use C# in the back-end, the server-side DTO has no `displayName` property).

Important: I'm trying to do this *without* changing the loading in the javascript and structure of the `options` and `selectedOption`. Specifically:

- I understand I can put some logic at the end of the controller method to "reset" `this.item` to a reference to the actual entry in `options`, but in my real code it's not so trivial (for one because async loading of options and selectedOption is involved).
- I also understand I could change both the `selectedOption` and individual `options` so the "composite key" is also available as a "single compound key" e.g. `part1and2: "3-101"`, but this requires me to admit (knowing that) I have an XY-Problem: I can't easily change the structure of those, because I'm cheating by binding my UI to the DTOs coming from the back-end, instead of having a proper view model to bridge the gap.

Is there a way to do this with a `track by` expression, i.e. is there a way to elegantly solve this in the binding expressions? Or do I *have* to resort to fixing this in controller or service code?

Comment: Is the displayName part of the JSON or is that just for show in this example?

Comment: I've added it as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be that you restructure the your JavaScript object before you bind it so that it will have another property called `part12` for example, and then track by that property :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but as I said, I know about that option but like to avoid it. I'll try to clarify this some more in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the displayName is part of the JSON response then you should add that aswell to the selectedOption when you set the option in the controller.

Here's a working example of how you could do it without it (if you have the display name in the default selectedOption then add "option as option.displayName.." instead)

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("fooCtrl", function() {
    // This comes from an Angular service / back-end:
    this.options = [
      { part1: 3, part2: 101, displayName: "Option 3-101" },
      { part1: 4, part2: 651, displayName: "Option 4-651" },
      { part1: 4, part2: 999, displayName: "Option 4-999" }
    ];

    this.item = { selectedOption: { part1: 4, part2: 651} };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="fooCtrl as vm">
  <select ng-options="option as ('Option ' + option.part1 + '-' + option.part2) for option in vm.options track by (option.part1 +'-'+ option.part2)"
          ng-model="vm.item.selectedOption"></select>
  <hr>
  Debug info:
  <pre>{{vm.item | json}}</pre>
</div>
```